# Using one @TestPropertySource for multiple test classes

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-test

In Spring is possible to use *@TestPropertySource* to override some properties or load a specific property file **for the annotated test class**.

Let's say I want to do the same stated above, but I don't want to copy and paste the same code block across all my test classes. Is it possible to have this configuration centralized in a class?

I tried to do something like:

```
@TestPropertySource(
        properties = {
                "DATABASE_URL: jdbc:h2:mem:test;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1",
                "DATABASE_DDL-AUTO:create-drop"
        },
        locations = {
                "classpath:persistence-${environment}.yml"
                }
)
@Configuration
public class MyConfigurationClass {

}
```

And later use **@Import** in my class test class, but I didn't make it work.

Is it possible?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best solution for this using `@Profile` and `@ActiveProfile` annotation on top of test classes. Add all the test properties into `application-test.yml` file and

**Use @Profile** To load the particular profile properties during test execution

**Use @ActiveProfile** for making profile active for that test execution

**TestOne**

```
  @Profile("test")       // for loading application-test.yml
  @ActiveProfile("test") // for activating test profile
  public class TestOne {
  }
```

**TestTwo**

```
  @Profile("test")       // for loading application-test.yml
  @ActiveProfile("test") // for activating test profile
  public class TestTwo {
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a parent class for all your tests with **@TestPropertySource** annotation.

Any component class (@Service, ..) with property **foo** (already loaded from application.properties or other properties file) to override in JUnit test :

```
@Component
public class AnyComponent {

    @Value("${foo}")
    private String foo;

    public String getFoo() {
        return foo;
    }

    public void setFoo(String foo) {
        this.foo = foo;
    }
}
```

Parent test class :

```
@TestPropertySource(properties = {"foo:bar"})
public class ParentTest {
}
```

Test class :

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class YourTest extends ParentTest {

    @Autowired
    private AnyComponent anyComponent;

    @Test
    public void myTest() {
        System.out.println(anyComponent.getFoo());
    }
}
```

In the same way your can create other tests sharing **@TestPropertySource**

Comment: I gonna give it a go when I get back home but just to add more details and leave it documented here, I think that in order to this to work I need to set the properties inheritProperties and inheritLocations to true.